# Purpose of assert in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, assert

I'm new to nodejs, I follow all the steps in the documentation. First I study and test the assert function of node, I just want to know what is the purpose of using assert? if no error there's no output, but if you have an error, there's an output saying AssertError etc.

I want to know, when and what is the purpose of using assert?

Comment: I don't think it's really any different from all other languages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)

Comment: when all else fails, refer to the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html

Comment: Well, one difference from, say, C++, is that in C++, assertions are compiled out of production code.  So you can put them in wherever, knowing they will not impact production performance. I'm not getting from the node.js doc that its assert is only for "development" mode.  So, perhaps it is premature optimization, but is assert intended for the code itself or only for test files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In any programming language errors are an issue. Whether by human error or poor design. The assert module in node.js is used to test the behavior of a function and reduce the creation of "buggy" code, this also promotes design thinking.

In most cases assertions are used in unit testing. This takes a unit of code, be it a function, method etc and runs multiple tests on it. These test the value that a function generates(actual) vs what we expect the function to provide.

An example of assertions:

```
"use strict";

//Run the code and change the values of x and y (to equal 42) to test the assert module.
const x = 18;
const y = 20;

//We have to import our assert module
var assert = require("assert");

//Calculates the anser to life (42)
var life = function(a,b){
    return a + b;
 };

//Overwrite the variable of result to equal the return.
result = life(x,y);

//Change the comments below to see the difference between the two values
assert.deepEqual(result, 42);
//assert.fail(result, 42, "", '<');
```

From a technical point of view, developers should write their tests before they start to write their code. This is a form of top-down development strategy, which allows developers to understand the functional requirements of the software. Therefore when writing your assertions you obtain the parameters you require and what results you expect. Thus making the logic the only hurdle.

Comment: Why should tests be written before the rest of the code?

Comment: Firstly, it will allow you you to understand what is required before you build without know what is required. 

For example you're told to write an API that performs X task. At that point you might have several assumptions that maybe incorrect. Writing a test would allow you to challenge your assumptions early, and then provide input/output expectations. It also allows you to work through the problem before spending time on the task itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assert is used to write test suites for your apps. This way, you can easily test your applications to see if they work as expected and catch errors early in the development stage .